# FLOT is only charting one value or is not drawing the whole graph

Tags: javascript, jquery, flot

My Flot chart is not graphing all my points.  It seems that the graph is only showing one of the values, just one bar in this case (no phone company jokes here).  Here is the initializer:

```
var mMainPlot= $.plot("#mainPlot", [{ data: getRandomData(), color: "rgba(20,60,200,0.9)" }], {
    bars: { show: true, barWidth: 0.8, fill: true, fillColor: "rgba(20,60,200,0.5)" },
    series: {
        color: "rgba(0,0,60,1)",
        lineWidth: 0,
        shadowSize: 4   //Faster w/o shadows
    },
    yaxis: {
        min: 20,
        tickSize: 20,
        tickFormatter: function (point) {
            return (point % 40 === 0) ? "" : point.toString();
        },
        max: 140
    },
    xaxis: {
        show: false
    },
    crosshair: {
        mode: "x", lineWidth: 12
    },
    grid: {
        hoverable: true, autoHighlight: false
    }
});
```

On a regular update, I query data from the server:

```
function update() {
    mMainPlot.setData([getOutsideData(LiveData)]);
    mMainPlot.draw();
}

function getOutsideData(values) {
    var largestVal = 0;
    var res = [];
    var i = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
        res.push([i, values[i]]);
        if (values[i] > largestVal)
            largestVal = values[i];
    }
    return res;
}
```

where `getOutsideData` returns: `[Array[2], Array[2], Array[2], Array[2], Array[2], Array[2], Array[2], Array[2], Array[2], Array[2], Array[2], Array[2], Array[2]]`.  As the plot is a bar graph it only shows one bar.  I can debug the functions and even the mMainPlot plot data holds the updating values that come from the server and changes with every update.

Comment: After your `setData` are you calling `mMainPlot.setupGrid()` and `mMainPlot.draw()` to redraw the chart (https://github.com/flot/flot/blob/master/API.md#plot-methods)?

Comment: @Mark yes the `update` function does actually call `draw`.  I was trimming the function down a little for posting here and failed to leave that call in.  Do I need to call `setupGrid()` every time I update as it "actually reinserts in the DOM"?  I don't recall seeing that it was needed from the documentation.

Comment: If the axeses change you need to call `setupGrid()`.

Comment: When I call the `setupGrid()` in my update function the data shows up.  But that is an expensive function to have to call every time.

Comment: @CaptainBli What makes you think that it's expensive?  Unless you're on a slow mobile device, or using IE7, I can't imagine you would notice a difference.

Comment: I am updating 4 times a second. Everything is expensive at this rate. It is changing/ rearranging the whole dom every time isn't it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it turns out, one does not need to call `setupGrid()` every time an update to the grid occurs.  Simply calling `draw()` is sufficient as long as the graph data is the only changing variable.  As stated in the comments to the question, `setupGrid()` should be called any time something other than the data is updated/changed.

In my case, the data was the only thing changing but the problem came from the initialization of the plot.

```
var mMainPlot= $.plot("#mainPlot", [{ data: getRandomData(), color: "rgba(20,60,200,0.9)" }], {
```

This built up my plot but the `getRandomData()` only returned a single data point.  So the plot only continued to display a single data point.  I updated the function to return the 13 points that I wished to have when the real data started streaming and it worked.

Moral: If you want to update your charts, be sure to initialize your plot correctly so that it will have the right number of data points to begin with.  If these change then call `setupGrid()` again to clean up the mis-aligned chart.